# ¿ Cómo podría unir una palabra después de usar strtok ya sin los delimitadores?

Tags: c++

Ejemplo:

> Cadena =” El día es caluroso, las personas se refrescaban con bebidas de frutas de temporada”.

```
CadenaSalida= “DÍA CALUROSO, PERSONAS REFRESCABAN BEBIDAS FRUTAS TEMPORADA”

char mensaje[40];
char nuevo[40];

cout<< "Hola"<<endl;
cout<< "Cual es tu mensaje?" <<endl;

cin.getline(mensaje, 40);//Entrada de dato    

cout<<endl;
strupr(mensaje);//Convierte a mayusculas.
cout<<"Mayusculas: "<< mensaje <<endl;
cout<<endl;

char separador[] = " ";
char *tkn = strtok(mensaje, separador);

while(tkn)
{
    cout<< tkn <<endl;
    tkn = strtok(NULL,separador);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución puede ser esta:

Basándonos en tu bucle:

```
while(tkn)
{
    cout<< tkn <<endl;
    tkn = strtok(NULL,separador);
}
```

Hacemos lo siguiente:

Iniciamos un indice a 0 previo al bucle

```
int i = 0;
```

Y luego dentro del bucle, iteramos sobre cada *token*, de forma que asignamos cada indice del *token* al indice general de la frase final:

```
while(tkn)
{
    for (int j=0;j<strlen(tkn);j++)
    {
        nuevo[i]=tkn[j];
        i++;
    }
    cout<< tkn <<endl;
    tkn = strtok(NULL,separador);
}
```

Por último añadimos el caracter `'\0'` al final de la nueva cadena

```
nuevo[i]='\0';
```

Pongo la solución completa. También he implementado una función `strupr` puesto que no es estandar y por ejemplo yo no la tenía.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
void strupr(char* frase);

int main()
{
    char CadenaSalida[]= "DIA CALUROSO, PERSONAS REFRESCABAN BEBIDAS FRUTAS TEMPORADA";

    char mensaje[40];
    char nuevo[40];

    cout<< "Hola"<<endl;
    cout<< "Cual es tu mensaje?" <<endl;

    cin.getline(mensaje, 40);//Entrada de dato

    cout<<endl;
    strupr(mensaje);//Convierte a mayusculas.
    cout<<"Mayusculas: "<< mensaje <<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    char separador[] = ",";
    char *tkn = strtok(mensaje, separador);

    int i = 0;
    while(tkn)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<strlen(tkn);j++)
        {
            nuevo[i]=tkn[j];
            i++;
        }
        tkn = strtok(NULL,separador);
    }
    nuevo[i]='\0';
    cout<<"Nuevo= "<<nuevo<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void strupr(char* frase)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (frase[i]!='\0')
    {
        if ((int)frase[i]>96 && (int)frase[i]<123)
        {
            frase[i] = (char)(frase[i]-32);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```